# Matplotlib - format with subscript and superscript

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, text, format

How to write this number format, please?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 8))
a = 2
b = 5
c = 5
plt.text(5, 400, "${}^+^{}_-_{}$ d.".format(a, b, c))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 8))
a = 2.003
b = 5.551
c = -6.661
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, "${0:f}^{{{1:+f}}}_{{{2:f}}}$".format(a,b,c))
plt.show()
```